Как сделать похожую разметку с использованием 100vh?

Вот это пример сайта который я нашел в интернете,  весь контент на экране неизменно занимает 100% высоты и я не понимаю как мне сделать что то подобное, сколько оберток делать, куда задать background-image, какой элемент должен отвечать за высоту и куда задать падинг чтоб он не сьел картинку
много всего перепробовал и даже забросил кодинг на несколько недель(

вот макет

Маргин авто тут мне кажется
